# Overriding resource controller

Tags: php, symfony, sonata-admin, sylius

I have a Symfony app that uses Sonata as the backend admin and the Sylius platform for product management.

I have created my own create route in the admin class configureRoutes method. I want to call our resource controller (that will be used to handle all product objects) CRUD methods from sonata.

Here is my configureRoutes method thus far:

```
    protected function configureRoutes(RouteCollection $collection)
    {
        $collection->add('create', 'create', array(
                '_controller' => 'AppBundle:Backend/Resource:createAction',
                '_sylius' => array(
                    'template' => 'AppBundle:Product/Backend/Form:CreateProduct.html.twig',
                    'redirect' => 'sylius_backend_product_show',
                )
            )
        );
    }
```

But I get the following error:

[image]

My resourceController extends the sylius resource controller:

```
namespace AppBundle\Controller\Backend;

use Sylius\Bundle\ResourceBundle\Controller\ResourceController as BaseController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

/**
 * Class ResourceController
 * @package AppBundle\Controller\Backend
 */
class ResourceController extends BaseController
{
    /**
     * @param Request $request
     *
     * @return RedirectResponse|Response
     */
    public function createAction(Request $request)
    {   
        // Custom view logic
        return parent::createAction($request);
    }
}
```

My app/config.yml:

```
sylius_product:
    driver: doctrine/orm
    classes:
        product:
            model: AppBundle\Entity\Product
            controller: AppBundle\Controller\Backend\ResourceController
            form:
                default: AppBundle\Form\Type\ProductType
            translatable:
                targetEntity: AppBundle\Entity\ProductTranslation
        product_translation:
            model: AppBundle\Entity\ProductTranslation

sylius_resource:
    resources:
         app.backend.product:
             driver: doctrine/orm
             object_manager: default
             classes:
                 controller: AppBundle\Controller\Backend\ResourceController
                 model: AppBundle\Entity\Product
```

How do I satisfy the constructor arguments?

Comment: Sylius controllers are services so should be called in the `sylius.controller.product:createAction` format rather than `Sylius:Product:create`.

Comment: Add that as an answer my man :)

Comment: Out of curiosity, from what you can see, can you do the same thing but for resource controller so you can call it by `sylius.controller.resource`.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sylius controllers are services so should be called in the `sylius.controller.product:createAction` format rather than `Sylius:Product:create`.

The resource bundle names the services based on your resource name (`app.backend.product`) but the naming is generated like...

```
list($prefix, $resourceName) = explode('.', $name);
```

...meaning that your prefix would be `app` and the resource name would become `backend` (`products` not even being included in the naming). As the resource controllers actions output are all controlled by the routing information there isn't really the need to have a specific `backend` controller. If any actions were needed to be just for backend routes you could always create `createBackendAction` although, as I mentioned, it's probably not necessary.